# using the value of the ValueMember property

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to retrieve the value stored in the "ValueMember" property of a ComboBox. I followed the advice from the following post: [How to get ValueMember value from ComboBox C# Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982929/how-to-get-valuemember-value-from-combobox-c-sharp-winforms)

Unfortunately it's not working. Below is my code:

```
Private Sub LoadCategoryCombo()
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    ds = GetCategoryData()

    If Not IsNothing(ds) Then
        cmbCategory.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "category"
        cmbCategory.ValueMember = "abbrev"
    End If
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is When I select a value from the dropdown list, I wish to display the value stored in the "ValueMember" field, however, it just displays "abbrev". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Tag this question with WPF or WinForms...whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the property Value not ValueMember

```
Dim valueMemberValue = cmbCategory.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

The property [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) it is just the name of the column from which you want to retrieve values while DiplayMember is the name of the column from which you want to populate the items collection.
So, setting the ValueMember, you tell the ComboBox to update its Value property when the user select a different item from the Items collection. The combo looks at the corresponding value present in the same row of the item selected but in the column named through the ValueMember property