# Visual Studio 2015 Combo Boxes

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

I am trying to use Combo boxes in a visual studio 2015 (I think this means its VB6 code)

I am trying to build a list of values from a MySQL ADODB.recordset I have been able to insert them into the combo box.

However, I have no idea how to get or set the value in the Combobox.

```
so cmbGenre.setValue(new Object / id assoiated with a object)    
or MsgBox("Current Select value in Combo box is = " & cmbGenre.selectObject)
```

The objGenre is just a class which has to variable ID & Name (this is all the columns in the MySQL table

```
Public Sub refreshCmbGenre(ByVal id As Long)
    Call rsSetup(TABLE_GENRES)
    cmbGenre.Items.Clear()
    rsGenres.Sort = FIELD_NAME
    rsGenres.MoveFirst()

    Do Until rsGenres.EOF
        cmbGenre.Items.Add(New objGenre(rsGenres.Fields(FIELD_ID).Value, rsGenres.Fields(FIELD_NAME).Value))
        rsGenres.MoveNext()
    Loop

'=====this is the problem code=========================
    rsGenres.MoveFirst()
    rsGenres.Find("[id]=" & id)
    cmbGenre.SelectedText = rsGenres.Fields(FIELD_NAME).Value
'=============================
End Sub
```

Comment: VB6 dates from Visual Studio 6 (I think in 1998 or around). VBA is based on VB6. Your code if written in VS 2015 is VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, it sounds like you are looking for this:

```
cmbGenre.SelectedIndex = cmbGenre.FindStringExact(rsGenres.Fields(FIELD_NAME).Value)
```

This will find the index of the combobox item that matches the field name, and then set the selection that item.

You can then get the values out using

```
cmbGenre.SelectedItem
```

This will return the object bound to the that item, containing both the ID and the FieldName.

This link should help with a better solution for working with comboboxes. It has a similar question in C# but is very easy to convert: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15983066/6144259

Comment: My pleasure! Out of interest, did you use the code I provided or use something from the link?

Comment: Yours the code looked like I had imaged it would be just didn't know that function "find string existed".  however I may need to look more in depth in the future as there may come a time duplicate string name are in the combo